Guardar nota después de buscar y reemplazar en Apache Zeppelin
Cuando importo una nota en Zeppelin en .json o .ipynb, por defecto se añade al principio:
%python en todos los paragraph. Son al rededor de 70 paragraph que tengo, y la solución que vi fue la de reemplazar %python por vacio.
Al darle clic al botón Seach code, aparece el cuadro para buscar y reemplazar el texto, pongo en Find %python y Replace lo dejo vacío:

Luego doy clic en All y reemplaza todo. El problema es que no lo reemplaza realmente porque cuando le doy a Run all paragraphs aparece "Interpreter python not found" o cuando me voy a atras me aparece el cuadro:

¿Cómo puedo guardar la nota despues de buscar y reemplazar?
P.D.: El intérprete por defecto es spark, no puedo utilizar otro.
